# Custom.js file is not working in Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a custom.js file that has some jQuery stuff and no matter what I do the jQuery events were not getting fired.

In the main.blade.php I have a  tag pointing to Google CDN. Then I have,

```
{{ HTML::script('js/custom.js') }}
```

And in the custom.js file I have a simple alert to make sure it's getting called,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("jQuery worked");
}
```

No matter what I do the alert is not getting popped. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if it's a copy-paste error, but you've got a problem with your custom.js file.  You're missing a closing bracket and semi colon at the end of that snippet.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("jQuery worked");
});
```

Comment: Thank you Andrew...that was it...it drove me nuts.